# jQuery Mobile freezes while scrolling

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, scroll, freeze

While scrolling my jQuery Mobile enabled site on a mobile device (at least iPhone 4 and 5), it almost always freezes for a few seconds, sometimes significantly longer. Usually it eventually just crashes and I have to kill Safari (or Chrome) from memory.

I'm having trouble identifying the cause. I know they state there are issues with transitions, and I tried adding `.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden }`, but it didn't help.

I'm guessing it might have to do with one or more scripts that are running. My scripts file essentially contains a set of scripts that run for both desktop and mobile, and two more sets that run exclusively for desktops and mobiles respectively. The common set is wrapped in a conditional ready function, `$(document).ready` for desktop and `$(document).on('pageinit)` for mobiles.

Also, based on the device, all the scripts are either loaded in the footer for desktops and the head for mobiles. However, the main scripts file is loaded in the footer for both. The scripts wouldn't work on mobiles otherwise.

Not sure if iOS preventing DOM manipulation on scroll is conflicting with something.

I would just link the site, but professional confidentiality and all that.

I'm not asking you to just guess what the cause may be, but I would really appreciate an outline of some fundamental principles of developing with jQuery Mobile to optimize performance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/events.html) (navigate to "scrollstart"), it is expected that DOM manipulation is frozen during scroll in iOS devices, even in iOS 7.